# Ising model metropolis algorithm: lattice won't equilibrate

Tags: python, physics, montecarlo

I have some code for the Ising model in python (2d), and the lattice won't reach an equilibrium. Here, the code prints out the number of spins that flip for each Monte Carlo sweep, and the same number are flipping for each sweep. If I'm correct, then the number that flip should decrease with each sweep, as the lattice reaches an equilibrium. Can anyone see any errors with the code?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rn
N=20
a=[1,-1]
b=[N,N]

#first make an array
init_lattice=rn.choice(a,size=(N,N))

#specify how many Monte Carlo sweeps
number_of_sweeps=1000

#main code to flip spins and record how many are flipped
def new_lattice(lattice,T):
    delta_E=np.zeros(b)
    switch1=np.zeros(number_of_sweeps)
    switch=0
    for sweep in range(number_of_sweeps):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                Si=lattice[i,j]
                sum_Sj=lattice[i,(j+1)%N]+lattice[(i+1)%N,j]+lattice[i,(j-1)%N]+lattice[(i-1)%N,j]
                delta_E[i,j]=2*Si*sum_Sj
                if delta_E[i,j]<0:
                    lattice[i,j]*=-1
                    switch+=1
                elif np.exp(-1*delta_E[i,j]/(T))>rn.random():
                    lattice[i,j]*=-1
                    switch+=1
        switch1[sweep]=switch
    return lattice,switch1

#print how many spins have flipped
switch= new_lattice(init_lattice,5)[1]
print switch
for i in range(len(switch)):
    print switch[i+1]-switch[i-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the loops

```
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
```

are not good: you must choose the spin you want to test randomly.

T and other variables are integer and you will have an integer division in the exponential np.exp(-1*delta_E[i,j] / T) which is wrong.

With this code I have a saturation (note I take T=1. instead of 5. and sweeps = 10000 instead of 1000):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rn
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latticeDimensions = [20, 20]
nx = latticeDimensions[0]
ny = latticeDimensions[1]
nodesNumber = nx*ny
spinValues = [-1,1]
sweeps = 10000
T = 1.

lattice = init_lattice = rn.choice(spinValues,size=(nx,ny))
#lattice = [ random.choice([-1,1]) for i in range(nodesNumber) ]
t = 0
switch = 0
res = []
while t < sweeps:
    selectedNode = random.choice(nodeIdx)
    i = random.choice(range(nx))
    j = random.choice(range(ny))
    Si = lattice[i,j]
    sum_Sj=lattice[i,(j+1)%ny] + lattice[(i+1)%nx,j] + lattice[i,(j-1)%ny] + lattice[(i-1)%nx,j]
    delta = 2 * Si * sum_Sj
    probaTemp = np.exp(- delta / T)
    if delta > 0. and rn.random() < probaTemp:
        lattice[i,j] *= -1
        switch += 1
    elif delta <= 0.:
        lattice[i,j] *= -1
        switch += 1
    t += 1
    print t
    res.append(switch)

plt.plot(res)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where is the sign error? The change in energy should be negative because the spin will switch to reduce the overall energy, not raise it.

Comment: I corrected my answer. You need to use a lower T (greater is T slower the convergence), and change the energy criterium as edited in my solution.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I don't understand though why my original elif condition isn't the same as your "and". It seems to me like you've just swapped them around, and in place of the elif you put "and". Why does this change it?

Comment: Indeed, the 2 conditions are equivalent from a formal point of view. I deleted the comments on the condition in my answer. You didn't observe saturation because of your simulation parameters (T too big and number of sweepstoo low), but there was 2 other problem (spin selection and exponential computation) that could false your results. Fell free to upvote and set the problem as solved if it's ok for you.